# a question on the induced morphism of arc schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of affine schemes. Denote by $X_{\infty},Y_{\infty}$ the arc schemes of $X$ and $Y$ respectively and $X_{x,\infty}$ be the closed subscheme of $X_{\infty}$ corresponding to arcs based at a closed point $x \in X$. We have an induced morphism
$f_{\infty,x} : X_{x,\infty} \rightarrow Y_{\infty}$. I am trying to understand the scheme theoretic image of $X_{x,\infty}$ under $f_{\infty}$. To begin with it is clear that if $P \in \mathbb{C}[Y]$ is such that $Pf \in \mathfrak{m}_x^{j}$, then $D^r(P)$ vanishes identically on $f_{\infty}(X_{x,\infty})$ for $0 \leq r < j$.
Let $I_{x,\infty}$ be the ideal generated by the set $\{D^iP \mid P \in \mathbb{C}[Y], Pf \in \mathfrak{m}_x^{i+1} \}$, where $D$ is the natural derivation on $\mathbb{C}[Y]$. From what we have seen above we have
$\overline{f_{\infty}(X_{x,\infty})}$ is a closed subscheme of $V(I_{x,\infty})$. But I am not able to show that they coincide.
So is the scheme theoretic image of $f_{\infty,x}$ given by
$V(I_{\infty,x})$?